# constexpr get index of item in array

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```cpp
static const char* ITEMS[] = { "a", "b" }  // too many elements for a std::array in my situation

void my_func() {
    printf("a: %d", index_of(ITEMS, "a"));  // 0
    printf("d: %d", index_of(ITEMS, "d"));  // error at compile time; "d" does not exist in ITEMS.
}
```

How would I define a similar `index_of` method? I've seen various suggestions on other SO posts, but they don't work for the following reasons:

- Use `std::string`/Make `ITEMS` a `constexpr`

  - Unfortunately ImGui's `Combo` requires a `const char**` for the array type which is impossible with `std::string`, and similarly, as `ITEMS` would be a `constexpr` it would be of type `const char* const *`, which does not work.
- Use `std::array` instead of `T[]`

  - The number of elements is too high for the compiler to handle, resulting in a compiler error.

Comment: "*too many elements for a std::array in my situation*" - `std::array<T,N>` is just a wrapper for a `T[N]` array, so they should have the same compiler limitations. "*The number of elements is too high for the compiler to handle, resulting in a compiler error*" - that would imply that your design is wrong to begin with and should be rewritten.

Comment: It can only possibly work at compile-time if it is guaranteed that the pointers themselves are `const`. If the pointers may be modified by a function, then they are not compile-time constants.

Comment: I can see some nuisance with the length of the `array` not being inferred, but other than that it's as Remy says: Same size.

Comment: > that would imply that your design is wrong to begin with and should be rewritten

using const char* ITEMS[] = { ... }  works fine, using auto ITEMS[] = std::array { ... } yields `In template: instantiating fold expression with 1821 arguments exceeded expression nesting limit of 256`

> It can only possibly work at compile-time if it is guaranteed that the pointers themselves are const
How would I specify this in code? None of them are modified at runtime.

Comment: @Martmists You can increase the instantiation limit with a compiler option and it occurs only because you are relying on CTAD to determined the array size instead of specifying it explicitly. (Although 256 does look like a small default limit to me as well.)

Comment: @Martmists If none of the pointers are modified, why does the library want a `const char**` instead of a `const char* const*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you *must* declare the array as `constexpr`. Otherwise its values are not usable at compile-time:

```
static constexpr const char* ITEMS[] = { "a", "b" };
```

As a consequence the type of the elements will be `const char* const`. If a library function expects them to be non-`const` then presumably that is because the library may attempt to modify them. That is of course impossible if they are supposed to be compile-time constants.

If you are absolutely sure that the library is simply lying about needing to modify the pointer value, then you can cast `const` away with `const_cast`. However, if the library then *does* attempt to modify the elements, then your program will have undefined behavior.

Then you also need C++20. Otherwise there is no way to force a compile-time error from failure of constant expression evaluation in a simple function call. Specifically you need the `consteval` feature.

With that:

```
template<typename R>
consteval auto index_of(const R& range, std::string_view needle) {
    auto it = std::ranges::find(range, needle);
    if(it == std::ranges::end(range))
        throw std::logic_error("Element not found!");
    return std::ranges::distance(std::ranges::begin(range), it);
}
```

This works with both built-in arrays and `std::array`.

Then you also need to replace `%d` with `%zu`, because the iterator difference type returned by this `index_of` is `std::size_t` for built-in arrays. `%d` is for the wrong type (`int`).

Comment: Is there a way to also define a non consteval overload as a fall back? I.e. the support both index_of(ITEMS, "a") and index_of(ITEMS, myObj.variable)? How does this work with overload resolutions

Comment: @bgura No, unfortunately that is currently impossible. You can't overload on `consteval` or whether the call would be a constant expression in general. It would however be possible if you are fine with implementing `index_of` as a macro. The standard library uses the trick for `std::format` to do compile-time format string checks. They chose to use a different function name `std::vformat` for the runtime form that doesn't perform these checks and can be called with runtime arguments.